# Using arrangeGrob to add a sub plot as a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, grob

I'm trying to graph two plots together, where one I a main plot and the other is a sub plot that I'd like to be located in the legend area of the main plot.

This code produces this plot:

```
gLegend <- function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)
} 

set.seed(1)
main.df <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:4],3),
                     y=rnorm(12),x=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),col=rep(c("gray","blue","red","magenta"),3))
main.df$group <- factor(main.df$group,levels=LETTERS[1:4])
sub.df <- data.frame(group=c("B","C","D"),x=1:3,effect=runif(3,0,1),col=c("blue","red","magenta"))
sub.df$group <- factor(sub.df$group,levels=LETTERS[2:4])

main.plot <- ggplot(main.df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(group)))+geom_point(size=3)+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=4)+scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray","blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("A","B","C","D"),name="group")+scale_colour_manual(values=c("gray","blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("A","B","C","D"),name="group")+scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(main.df$x))
sub.plot <- ggplot(sub.df,aes(x=x,y=effect,color=factor(group)))+geom_point(size=2)+scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("B","C","D"),name="group",guide=FALSE)+scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("B","C","D"),name="group",guide=FALSE)+labs(x="group",y="effect")+ggtitle("effect summary")+scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(sub.df$x),labels=c("B","C","D"))

sub.plot.grob <- ggplotGrob(sub.plot)
combined.plot <- arrangeGrob(main.plot+theme(legend.position="none"),widths=c(0.75,0.25),arrangeGrob(20,sub.plot.grob),ncol=2)
```

[image]

What I'd like to do is get rid of the legend of the main plot.

If I add `guide=FALSE` to `scale_fill_manual` `scale_colour_manual` `gLegend` throws the error:

```
Error in tmp$grobs[[leg]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

Obviously because it cannot fine `"guide-box"`

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here is an alternative solution using `cowplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_bw()) #cowplot automatically sets theme_classic

set.seed(1)
main.df <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:4],3),
                      y=rnorm(12),x=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),col=rep(c("gray","blue","red","magenta"),3))
main.df$group <- factor(main.df$group,levels=LETTERS[1:4])
sub.df <-     data.frame(group=c("B","C","D"),x=1:3,effect=runif(3,0,1),col=c("blue","red","magenta"))
sub.df$group <- factor(sub.df$group,levels=LETTERS[2:4])

sub.plot <- ggplot(sub.df,aes(x=x,y=effect,color=factor(group)))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("B","C","D"),name="group",guide=FALSE)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("B","C","D"),name="group",guide=FALSE)+
  labs(x="group",y="effect")+
  ggtitle("effect summary")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(sub.df$x),labels=c("B","C","D"))


main.plot <- ggplot(main.df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(group)))+
  geom_point(size=3)+facet_wrap(~group,ncol=4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray","blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("A","B","C","D"),name="group")+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("gray","blue","red","magenta"),labels=c("A","B","C","D"),name="group")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=unique(main.df$x)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(main.plot, x = 0, y = 0, width = 0.75, height = 1) +
  draw_plot(sub.plot, 0.75, 0, .25, .5)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
grid.arrange(ggplot(), ggplot(), 
             layout_matrix=matrix(c(1,1,NA,2), 2), widths=c(1.5,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using `grid` package, if you want a blank space where is the current legend:

[image]

```
library(grid)

set.seed(1)
main.df <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:4],3),
                  y = rnorm(12),
                  x = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4)),
                  col = rep(c("gray", "blue", "red", "magenta"), 3))
main.df$group <- factor(main.df$group,levels=LETTERS[1:4])

sub.df <- data.frame(group=c("B", "C", "D"),
                 x = 1:3,
                 effect = runif(3, 0, 1),
                 col = c("blue", "red", "magenta"))
sub.df$group <- factor(sub.df$group, levels=LETTERS[2:4])

main.plot <- ggplot(main.df, aes(x = x,y = y, color = factor(group))) + 
geom_point(size = 3) + facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 4) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray", "blue", "red", "magenta"), 
labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),name = "group") + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("gray", "blue", "red", "magenta"), 
labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), name = "group") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(main.df$x)) + guides(color = F)

sub.plot <- ggplot(sub.df, aes(x = x, y = effect, color = factor(group))) +
geom_point(size = 2) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "magenta"), 
labels = c("B", "C", "D"), name= "group" ,guide = FALSE) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "magenta"), 
labels = c("B", "C", "D"), name = "group", guide=FALSE) + 
labs(x = "group", y = "effect") + 
ggtitle("effect summary") + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(sub.df$x), labels = c("B", "C", "D"))


blank = grid.rect(gp = gpar(col = "white"))

sub.plot.grob <- arrangeGrob(blank, sub.plot, ncol = 1)

combined.plot <- arrangeGrob(main.plot, sub.plot.grob, ncol=2, widths=c(0.75,0.25))

grid.arrange(combined.plot)
```